# Codeigniter doesn't find url throws 404 Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes

I have the following routes in codeigniter:

```
$route['register/new/user/from=(:any)'] = "auth/user/register/index/$1";
$route['default_controller'] = "defaultcontroller";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

and also I have this hierarchy in my controllers folder:

```
auth
   |-------admin
   |-------member
   |-------user
             |----register.php
             |----tester.php
```

When I try to access `http://host/index.php/auth/user/register/index/` or `http://host/index.php/register/new/user/from=www.google.com` it throws **404 not found** error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

you can use this line code if your codes are inside index method :

> $route['register/new/user/from/:any'] = "auth/user/register/index/$1";

You should change the **auth/user/register/index/$1** to **register/new/user/from/:any** or **register/new/user/:any** and use **segment(4)**

Comment: @ramin please my answee validated if it'sthe best one

Answer (score 1):

```
$route['register/new/user/(:any)'] = "auth/user/register/index/$1";
```

or

```
$route['register/new/user/from/(:any)'] = "auth/user/register/index/$1";
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Your URL format itself has problems; you should *normalize* your URL.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization

You cannot use an equal to "=" symbol in a *segment* in a normalized URL.

You CAN use the "=" symbol in a query string.

So instead of

```
http://host/index.php/register/new/user/from=www.google.com
```

(Wrong / Not Normalized)

Try:

```
http://host/index.php/register/new/user/?from=www.google.com
```

(Correct: Query String)

Or:

```
http://host/index.php/register/new/user/from%3Dwww.google.com
```

(Correct but not recommended: URI Encoded String)

Or:

```
http://host/index.php/register/new/user/from/www.google.com
```

(Correct: Separate Segments)

You can capture the last one with

```
$route['register/new/user/from/(:any)'] = "auth/user/register/index/$1";
```